# How to Use LocalResourceObject in static methods [webmethod]

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, localization, webmethod

I can simply use localisation in aspx page but cannot use in aspx.cs files.

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string Menu(int role, int driver)
    {
 string _permissions = dr["FN_2"].ToString().Replace(" /V*", System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("CRL.aspx", "RV.Text").ToString());
// This way didn't get error in coding but when I run it, give me no permission error for virtual path

string _permissions = dr["FN_2"].ToString().Replace(" /V*", System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("RV.Text").ToString());
//I cannot use in this way
    }
```

In aspx page, I can call it `GetLocalResourceObject("RV.Text")` like this.
I have to get reach these localisation stuff, I need them for a lot things.

I cannot return text from localresource object in these two ways. One of them get error while coding, other one cannot reach the virtual path due to permission. How can I use `GetLocalResourceObject` in `[WebMethod]`?

Comment: What is your question, it is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try static string:

```
public static string _RV { get; set; }
```

then you fill it where you want eg. Page_Load:

```
_RV = GetLocalResourceObject("RV.Text").ToString();
```

and then you can run it well:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Menu(int role, int driver)
    {
     string _permissions = dr["FN_2"].ToString().Replace(" /V*", _RV);    
    }
```

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this:
`string _permissions = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/×××/×××.aspx", "RV.Text").ToString();`